# Proving $ \frac{1}{t} < \ln (t) - \ln (t-1) < \frac {1}{t-1}, $ for $t>1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Prove that if $t>1$ then,

$$ \frac{1}{t} < \ln (t) - \ln (t-1) < \frac {1}{t-1}. $$

Any kind of input on this problem would be most appreciated!

Comment: What are you allowed to assume? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 5):

I think that using the [Mean value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) would be helful to see that if $0<a<b$ then $$(1-a/b)<\ln(b/a)<(b/a-1)$$

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was thinking of working with this theorem but wasn't sure how to apply it.

Comment: @user108626: Indeed, regarding to our assumptions for the function $\ln(x)$, there is an $0<a<\xi<b$ such that $1/t<1/\xi<1/(t-1)$.

Comment: This makes so much sense! I struggle with proofs so thanks for your help!

Comment: Well done! $+1$

Answer (score 5):

By the mean value theorem on the interval $[t-1,t]$ using the function $\log$ : there's $c\in (t-1,t)$ 
$$\log t-\log(t-1)=\frac{1}{c}$$
and since $0<t-1<c<t$ we find that
$$\frac{1}{t}<\frac{1}{c}=\log t-\log(t-1)<\frac{1}{t-1}$$

Comment: This is a great technique, but I'm having trouble understanding how you realized that MVT would help, and how you figured out how to do so.

Comment: This method is classic and I teach this technique every year:-)

Comment: In what context do you teach it? How can I recognize a problem it likely applies to?

Comment: In the chapter *differentiability* for the first year undergraduate. You should think  to use MVT whenever you see $f(a)-f(b)$.

Comment: Makes sense. Maybe it's been too long since I studied calculus. Then again, maybe I find other things more interesting.

Comment: This has been very helpful! Thanks so much!

Comment: @user108626 You're welcome.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: We had telepathic approach in solving this question. :+)

Answer (score 2):

Using the concavity inequality $\ln(1+u) \leq u$ (with equality iff $u = 0$), one has
$$
\ln (t) - \ln(t-1) = -\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right) >\frac{1}{t}
$$
for the lower bound, and for the upper bound:
$$
\ln(t) - \ln(t-1) = \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{t-1}\right) < \frac{1}{t-1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\ln(t) - \ln(t-1) = \ln\left( \frac{t}{t-1} \right) = \ln\left( 1 + \frac{1}{t-1}\right)$$

Now if we differentiate this function we find: $$\frac{d}{dx} \ln\left( 1 + \frac{1}{t-1}\right) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{t-1}} \cdot \frac{-1}{(t-1)^2} = \frac{-1}{t(t-1)}$$

Notice that for $t>1$ this is smaller than the derivative of $1/(t-1)$, but larger than the derivative of $1/t$.

Now if you can find a point, $t_0 > 1$ where this equality holds, you can conclude the inequality holds for all $t > 1$.