# Prove inequality using mean value theorem 1/(x+1) < ln(x+1) - ln(x) < 1/x

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Using the mean value theorem of lagrange I need to prove that for all x > 0:
$$
\frac{1}{x+1} < ln(x+1) - ln(x) < \frac{1}{x}
$$

I was able to reach the following solution:
$$f(x) = ln(x+1)$$
The then derive the function:
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$$
apply mvt on (0,x):
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \frac{ln(x+1)}{x}$$
$$o<c<x$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{c+1}$$
$$\frac{1}{x+1} < \frac{ln(x+1)}{x} < 1$$
$$\frac{x}{x+1} < \ln(x+1) < x$$
$$\frac{x}{x+1} - ln(x)< \ln(x+1) - ln(x)< x - ln(x)$$

But I can't find way to continue from here.

Comment: I suppose you meant "for all $\;x>0\;$ ", otherwise logarithm isn't well defined...

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/582249/42969 - All found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%2B1%7D%20%3C%20%5Cln(x%2B1)%20-%20%5Cln(x)%20%3C%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%24)